# Image re-sizing on mobile devices

Tags: responsive-design

I'm a musician working on my personal website (not a programmer but I'm trying). I have the site looking ok in my web browser, but when I look at it on my phone the background image and buttons gets cut off and don't seem to be re-sizing to fit the browser window.  http://www.deathstarsky.com.

Thanks everyone, I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Hello Gage, welcome to SO:SE. You'll find great support here if you can provide additional elements as explained in [ask], for example which language do you use to  create your pages, and what is your current relevant code which can be reviewed. You may edit your question to improve it rather than to post a comment. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It will be simpler to use something like [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) rather than trying to write your own code to resize based on devices. Bootstrap takes care of all the details for you.

Answer (score 0):

Websites don't automatically scale on mobile phones.  You have the container set to 1000 pixels, and the width of a typical mobile phone browser is 320 pixels.

The design you have (which looks great on a browser) won't really scale properly to mobile anyway.  I'd recommend a mobile specific design, and have some server side code (such as php) that redirects users to the appropriate page.

Answer (score 0):

Add this css to your styling

```
.container {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 65%;
    width: 100%;
}
```